# A problem of prime elements on a number field $L$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Problem 1.7 (of Otto Endler's book "Teoria dos numeros algebricos")

Let $L$ be an algebraic number field and $A$ the ring of integers of $L$. Show that  if $\pi$ is a prime element of $A$, then $\pi$ is a divisor of an unique natural prime integer $p\in\mathbb{Z}$

My Aproach:  Since $\pi$ is a prime element of $A$, then $\pi$ is irredutible in $A$. This implies that $N_{L,\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)\neq 1,-1$ and (since $N_{L,\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)\in\mathbb{Z}$) then

$$N_{L,\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)=\pm p_{1}^{e_{1}}\cdots p_{k}^{e_{k}}$$

where $p_{1},\dots ,p_{k}$ are natural prime numbers

On the other hand by a well know Theorem $\pi$ is a divisor of $N_{L,\mathbb{Q}}(\pi)$ in $A$. Hence, $\pi$ is a divisor of some $p_{j}$ in $A$.

My question is: how to proof that $p$ is unique

Comment: Hint: $A\pi\cap \Bbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$. More generally, if $R\subset S$ are commutative rings and $\mathfrak{P}$ is a prime ideal of $S$, then $\mathfrak{P}\cap R$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Do you see why? It is possible that this piece of commutative algebra has not been covered yet. But it is good to learn. It's all over the place.

Comment: Any factor of two integers $a$ and $b$ is a factor of every $\mathbf Z$-linear combination of them, such as their gcd. Therefore $\pi$ can't divide two different prime numbers, as it would then divide $1$ and be a unit.

Comment: @KCd Thank you so much.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much